# StackOverflow with Lettuce using Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, lettuce

StackOverflow occurs when the app is started on AWS ECS and connects to AWS Elasticache Redis cluster. On local environment everything works fine. Also if Redis client is switched to Jedis the problem also does not occurs. The app is started in Docker container.

Stack:

- Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE
- OpenJDK 10
- Spring Data Redis (from Spring Boot Starter BOM)

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.lang.Math.floorDiv(Math.java:1195)
at java.base/java.lang.Math.floorMod(Math.java:1304)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(LocalDateTime.java:421)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.ofInstant(LocalDateTime.java:398)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipUtils.javaToDosTime(ZipUtils.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipUtils.javaToExtendedDosTime(ZipUtils.java:158)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipEntry.setTime(ZipEntry.java:168)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry.<init>(JarEntry.java:58)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:327)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.doGetEntry(JarFileEntries.java:295)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:248)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:219)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:210)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:102)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:169)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:646)
```